# rotating div with jquery and adding css classes with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, transform

I have a div, when you click it I want it to rotate and then when you click it again it rotates back, a toggle.  I'm doing this with CSS transforms, and I need to add the classes also with jquery.  I have the classes stored in vars and then am trying to apply them.  Here is the jfiddle I'm working on, thanks for your help in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/nzLUS/3/

here is the code:

```
<div id="beffects_of_yoga_info" style="width:50px;height:50px;background:red;"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var css_info_timing = {
"-webkit-transform": "all 1s ease;"
}
var css_info_rotate = {
"-webkit-transition": "rotate(150deg)"
}

$("#effects_of_yoga_info").css(css_info_timing);

$("#effects_of_yoga_info").click(function () {
$("#effects_of_yoga_info").toggleClass(css_info_rotate);
});
});
```

Comment: you should post code here also

Comment: You might want to check your jsFiddle code. `css_info_timing` should use `-webkit-transition`, and `css_info_rotate` should use `-webkit-transform`. Also, `css_info_rotate` is not a class, so you shouldn't use `toggleClass()` with that variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you're using `toggleClass`, but you're actually trying to toggle a property!

```
 $("#effects_of_yoga_info").toggleClass(css_info_rotate);
```

---

First of all, add this css class:

```
.rotated {
    -moz-transform:rotate(150deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(150deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(150deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(150deg);
    transform:rotate(150deg);
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
    -o-transition:all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 1s ease;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}​
```

Then this jQuery listener:

```
$("#effects_of_yoga_info").click(function () {
    $("#effects_of_yoga_info").toggleClass('rotated');
});
```

[Check the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/dSTyG/)

---

### Edit

As you don't have access to CSS, use this code to add the rule dinamically:

```
$("<style type='text/css'>.rotated{-moz-transform:rotate(150deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(150deg);-o-transform:rotate(150deg);-ms-transform:rotate(150deg);transform:rotate(150deg);-moz-transition:all 1s ease;-webkit-transition:all 1s ease;-o-transition:all 1s ease;-ms-transition:all 1s ease;transition:all 1s ease}</style>").appendTo("head");

$("#effects_of_yoga_info").click(function () {
    $("#effects_of_yoga_info").toggleClass('rotated');
});
```

[Another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/wULr3/)

Comment: so I need to add the css with the jquery specifically, and then I also need to animate it, that's why I had tried to make the two variables with the css.

Comment: oo, looks nice.  But is it possible to add that class all in the jquery, sorry I explained that poorly.  I don't have access to the CSS portion so I need to do it all with the script, that's why I had tried to do it with variables, haha but then the toggle doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @loriensleafs ok, give me 2 mins

Comment: errr, this runs into the same issue of my needing the css to be added all through the jquery, I dont' have access to the CSS, that's why I had tried but failed at defining them with variables.

Comment: that is very very helpful, thanks so much.  One last question, when you add the classes like so $("<style type='text/css'>.rotated{-moz-transform:rotate(150deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(150deg);-o-transform:rotate(150deg);-ms-transform:rotate(150deg);transform:rotate(150deg);-moz-transition:all 1s ease;-webkit-transition:all 1s ease;-o-transition:all 1s ease;-ms-transition:all 1s ease;transition:all 1s ease}</style>").appendTo("head");
can any script access them?  Or if starting a new script would you have to define them again?

Comment: @loriensleafs it will add it to the `<head>` section of your document, so once you add it one time it will be applicable to any element on that page

Comment: hmm, okay so I'm using thie program called interwoven and an limited but the department asked me if i could find a way around the restrictions.  What happens when I do that is it converts it to $("<div mce_name="style">. for some reason, which obviously doesn't work which is really to bad because it was much simpler then:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Build your CSS.
  var css_goto_img = {
    "opacity": ".5",
    "margin-left": "5px",
    "margin-top": "4px"
  }
  //Apply your CSS to the body tag.  You can enter any tag here, as
  //well as ID's and Classes.
  $("#effects_of_yoga_goto").css(css_goto_img);
});
// --></script>  which I had been using.  Any other thoughts on how to add that css into the script?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17309/discussion-between-loriensleafs-and-gionaf)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="effects_of_yoga_info" style="width:50px;height:50px;background:red;"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#effects_of_yoga_info{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s
}
.css_info_rotate {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(150deg);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#effects_of_yoga_info").click(function () {
        $("#effects_of_yoga_info").toggleClass('css_info_rotate');
    });
})
```

**DEMO**     http://jsfiddle.net/Nsryy/

​

Comment: This answer helped me! It simply rewinds the animation. Is there any way to instead continue the rotation, so it turns 360 degrees?